# Django Form has no attribute get

Tags: python, django

I have an form

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    status = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=Maca.Status.choices,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"class": "radio-ul"}),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ["status", "commission"]
```

I try to update the object with class based view

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       entries = UsersProductConfig.objects.get(pk=request.POST["object_id"])
       maca = EntryForm(request.POST or None, instance=entries)
       if maca.is_valid():
          maca.save()
       return maca
```

But I got the following error

```
'EntryForm' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

Class based views are not my strength, and I don't have your full view, but one possibility is that you do not have a get() method to check for get requests.  I'm thinking something like,

```py
def get(self, request):
   maca = EntryForm()
   return maca
```

Source: [Django - 'ContactForm' object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563608/django-contactform-object-has-no-attribute-get)